# "To improve reliability TimeMachine must create a new back up" leads to "there isn't enough space on xxxx" where xxxx has twice the capacity required

Tags: backup, time-machine, imac, mojave, nas

So I clicked on the 'make new backup' button thinking it would solve the issue it was complaining about and now it tells me that "there is not enough space on XXXX" to do this.

My iMac has a 1TB drive, the NAS I am backing up to has a 2TB drive.
It has been working fine for months.

I also have a second occasional back up to an external HDD with a 2TB and this has never had any issues.

What has happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the make and mode of the NAS? That might make a difference (but I suspect not my experience is that TM does this often on NAS)

Comment: So I understand that a NAS can cause the first issue but why is it now saying there is no space, given that it was quite happy backing up to the NAS for months? @mmmmmm

Comment: NAS is a Synology DS218+ (2 x 4TB, WD Red) @mmmmmm